# How can I tell Magento to use PayPalUK instead of PayPal?

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, nvp-gateway-error

I ran into a PayPal issue on a Magento Multistore (US, UK). Magento 1.7.0.2

The problem is that PayPal is rejecting the orders on the UK site. It is throwing following exception:

PayPal response hasn't required fields. files/html/app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:1011

I figured out that the required fields are different in UK and US:

```
files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php
    protected $_requiredResponseParams = array(
        self::DO_DIRECT_PAYMENT => array('ACK', 'CORRELATIONID', 'AMT')
    );


files/html/app/code/core/Mage/PaypalUk/Model/Api/Nvp.php
    protected $_requiredResponseParams = array(
        self::DO_DIRECT_PAYMENT => array('RESULT', 'PNREF', 'PPREF')
    );
```

I caught the PayPal response and found out that the PayPal response is different - depending on the store. The response in UK didn't contain the parameter 'ACK' and 'CORRELATIONID'.
So I assume the issue occurs because Magento is using the wrong Nvp.php (the standard one, not from the PayPalUk version). But how can I tell Magento to use the UK one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change **Merchant Country** setting in the admin to **UK**. Then Magento will use PaypalUk module.